# Why i am getting VB 2010 "Expression Expected" Error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a Point of Sale Application in VB.NET , i want to update the data in database but when i try i get Expression Expected error.

**PS:** I am using visual studio 2010 professional and operating system windows 10.If more explanation  is needed just mention in comments.

**Code:**

```
ProductTableAdapter.UpdateProduct('ProductNameTextBox.Text','QuantityTextBox.Text','SellingPriceTextBox.Text', 'IDTextBox.Text')
```

**Dataset Query Configuration :**

```
UPDATE `product` SET `ProductName` = ?, `Quantity` = ?, `SellingPrice` = ? WHERE ((`ID` = ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove brackets around where clause:

```
UPDATE `product` SET `ProductName` = ?, `Quantity` = ?, `SellingPrice` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?
```

Comment: You saved my 3 hours , it was perfect !

Comment: No problem. Cheers 1!!